# free-jqgrid: get 'lastSelectedData' after formatters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using free-jqgrid 4.9.0

is there a way to get the data from your grid just like with:

```
$("#my_grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastSelectedData');
```

but after the fields' values have been modified by formatters defined in the `colModel`?

**update:** <strike>*I am talking about custom-formatters, the built-in formatters seem to apply to the data.*</strike> actually the built-in formatters as well don't apply to the `data`.

thanks for any hints and help!

Comment: Which formatters you mean? Do you use custom formatters? In general the formatter represent **HTML fragments** generated from the data. So it's not clear for me what you mean and what case you have. Other methods like `getRowData`, `getCell` or `getCol` call **unformatter** explicitly to convert the displayed information back to data. So it's unclear for me what you need.

Comment: yes, i am talking about **custom formatters**. seems like the built-in formatters are applied to the `lastSelectedData`. I am using custom formatters not only for html-formatting but also to prepare data for the user like for example converting `1` and `0` values to `yes` and `no`.

Comment: It's better you append the text of the example what you do. I suppose that you could use custom formatter in a wrong way. **Do you defined unformatter too?** `colModel` and the custom formatter which you use should be included together with input data. You should explain on the example of test data what output data you need.

Comment: thanks, oleg. but i really just want to know if there is a way to apply my custom formatters automatically to the data i get by `$("#my_grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastSelectedData');`. or do you mean that they should apply automatically if i used my formatters correctly?

Comment: `lastSelectedData` like `data` allows you to get the reference to internal data used by jqGrid. You can't change the internal objects and it could be no additional options, because you get the data like it exists in jqGrid. You should post more details in the text of your question. I explained you that formatters produces **HTML fragments** from the data. So I really don't understand your question. You should explain it **on an clear example**.

Comment: like i mentioned - i use formatters to do simple things like turn `0` and `1` to `yes` and `no`. and **there are also built-in formatters that don't produce HTML fragments** - think of the `'date'` formatter, it only changes text and doesn't produce html. but thanks anyway, you answered my question - there is no built-in way to achieve what i want. In the mean time I have already coded something that helps me to convert the original `data` into "formatted data" for a CSV export.

Comment: You are welcome! If you exactly examine the results of `$("#my_grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastSelectedData');` you will see that **no** properties apply formatters. You can examine integer, number for example (if you use the corresponding formatter) to see which character will be used as decimal separator or as thousand separator. In general there are one common rule: one *should* use language independent formats to transfer/import/export the data. For example numbers without thousand separator and with dot as decimal separator (like JSON use), date in ISO format and so on.

Comment: yes but under some conditions it can be very useful to have the data with all your formatting, like in my case - if you want to export the data to a `CSV` format file. I have written a small plugin for free-jqgrid where you can simply add `{ ... csv : true ... }` to your `colModel`. when you then use the export function of my plugin it reads only data from the columns with `csv : true` and copies them to another array of objects with all formatters(custom- and built-in) applied. this data can be sent to a `PHP` script (for example) and can be easily converted to any `CSV` format.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that exporting *formatted* data is wrong in the common case. Depend on locale used in jqGrid and depend on the formetter options you can have wrong data during importing of such CSV. It could be that you have good results in case of the settings which you have in your current grid, but I think it's wrong in common case. Just think about different format of numbers used in different locals and about the format of dates. One can have wrong data after importing of such data in Excel for example (depend on locale of Excel). Some European CSV/DSV file  use `;` instead of `,`

Comment: no problem, i like criticism. but i don't think I use it wrong for what i want. i want a 1:1 representation (or "snapshot") of the jqGrid output in CSV. That's why I want the data 1:1 like it's representated in the grid - not how it's saved internally. which CSV format it is converted to is then the task of the PHP interface; and caring about character encoding and "bad character"-masking  as well is done by the PHP interface. so what i generate in my js-plugin is a data array with the output values of the jqGrid-columns which are marked for it for further processing.